# When saving a dictionary, the first letter is always lower case

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a project that used .net core 7.0, I'm saving some information in CosmoDB.
When I save an object in Cosmos Db, which contains a dictionary, the first letter of the key is always set to lower case, in some scenarios, the entire string is lowcase, in others just the first letter

Example 1:
Key = TEst
Value = TEST

[image]

Example 2:
Key = TEST
Value = TEST

[image]

I want to keep the string exactly as it was entered by the user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: One possible reason is your SDK client is using camel case for its serialization options. However you have to set it to do this as the default just accepts what you give it. Docs on this setting are here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmospropertynamingpolicy?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score -2):

> I want to keep the string exactly as it was entered by the user.

**Below are the steps I followed to keep the string exactly as it was entered by the user:**

- The **endpointUri** and **primaryKey** are used to create a `CosmosClient` instance.
- **databaseId** and **containerId** are used by `CosmosClient` to retrieve references to already existing databases and containers.
- **MyDocument** includes a unique Id generated using `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`, a **Name**, and a **DataDict** dictionary.
- `CreateItemAsync` method is used to insert the **myObject** document into the Cosmos DB container.
- Using the document's **Id** as a basis, it determines the partition key.

**Code I tried with:**

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string endpointUri = "*****";
        string primaryKey = "*****";
        string databaseId = "dictDb";
        string containerId = "dictCont";
        
        CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpointUri, primaryKey);

        Database database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseId);
        Container container = database.GetContainer(containerId);

        try
        {
            var myObject = new MyDocument
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), // Unique ID
                Name = "PaVaN bAlAjI T@dUtUrU",
                DataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "fIrSt NaMe", "PaVaN" },
                    { "MiDdLe nAmE", "bAlAjI" },
                    { "lAsT NaMe", "T@dUtUrU" },
                    { "aGe", "25"}
                }
            };

            ItemResponse<MyDocument> response = await container.CreateItemAsync(myObject, new PartitionKey(myObject.Id));

            Console.WriteLine($"Inserted item with ID: {response.Resource.Id}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

**In Console:**

```
Inserted item with ID: 97ba040f-890a-472a-85d7-399994aa322d
```

**After running a Query `SELECT * FROM C`:**

```js
{
    "id": "97ba040f-890a-472a-85d7-399994aa322d",
    "Name": "PaVaN bAlAjI T@dUtUrU",
    "DataDict": {
        "fIrSt NaMe": "PaVaN",
        "MiDdLe nAmE": "bAlAjI",
        "lAsT NaMe": "T@dUtUrU",
        "aGe": "25"
    }
}
```